# What is the normal rendering time?

Tags: adobe-media-encoder, rendering

I have i3-7100 CPU and 16 gigabytes of DDR4 RAM. I know it's not much, but **why Adobe Media Encoder 2020 is rendering my simple 720p video with subtitles so slow?!**

**It takes 20 minutes to render my 5 minute 720p video** with default H264 settings. What is going on here?

And there are no scaling or other effects. Just the video and hardcoded subtitles.

Comment: 20 minutes to render a 5 minute video on a slower machine doesn't sound that bad to me. Videos take ages in general. Often I end up rendering stuff overnight.

Comment: I quite often find rendering in Premiere is faster and more reliable than using Media Encoder fyi

Answer (score 2):

Check your GPU settings in AME prefs should be targeting your particular GPU. Choice of GPU can effect render time significantly. A GPU with a high CUDA processor count is best for these renders on a PC. On a MAC it should be metal with an appropriate card. Try and get a view of your system performance and buy a better card. https://www.cgdirector.com/best-cpu-gpu-render-benchmarks/